# No syntax-error message from MSX BASIC `SCREEN` command

Tags: msx

On bluemsx,  for the machine just labelled MSX,  adding a '.' full-stop after SCREEN 2 and typing various different types of rubbish does not generate a syntax error message .

SCREEN 2.11111

Noticed this when trying to see if there were any hidden screen-modes for faster graphics ( I have read about why msx is so slow and about the chip, but thought maybe a completely unknown mode may exist inherited from an earlier version of the chip, a single color monochrome mode.

Comment: What is a 'bluemsx'? Mind to add information about the environment like macine and MSX version?

Comment: The single colour monochrome mode is `SCREEN 0`, though you lose sprites and it’s technically a reprogrammable character map; you can also use `SCREEN 2` and just don’t upload new colour attributes — it’s basically a 1bpp mode in which you set the palette at 8x1 precision. So just update the pixels, not the colours. Lots of lazy Spectrum ports do it.

Answer (score 8):

> On bluemsx, for the machine just labelled MSX, adding a '.' full-stop after SCREEN 2 and typing various different types of rubbish does not generate a syntax error message .
>
> SCREEN 2.11111

This doesn't look like 'rubbish' but a valid floating point number. A number is a valid parameter to `SCREEN`, so no reason to raise any *'Syntax Error'* - try real rubbish, for example `SCREEN 2.abc` and you'll get the desired error.

When interpreting BASIC collects all digits and uses the integer part - '2' in this case - which is a legal screen mode, thus no reason to raise an *'Illegal Function Call'* error.

Bottom line: Nothing to see here, **everything as expected.**

Answer (score 2):

BASIC takes *value of* first argument into the DAC and explicitly uses CINT (2F8A) function to convert numerical type to integer. In the example below I entered `SCREEN 2.222` (41 22 22, with VALTYP=04). You can get error only if it is unable to convert the value, or BASIC is unable to understand the argument itself (not numerical value/string `SCREEN a$` or invalid string of variable name `SCREEN $a`).

[image]